# Does ArchiveIndexView inherit make_object_list?

Tags: django-views

Django 1.8.0

This is an example from Django Unleashed by Andrew Pinkham:

```
class PostList(ArchiveIndexView):
    allow_empty = True
    allow_future = True
    context_object_name = 'post_list'
    date_field = 'pub_date'
    make_object_list = True
    model = Post
    paginate_by = 5
    template_name = 'blog/post_list.html'
```

This is address from their GitHub:
https://github.com/jambonrose/DjangoUnleashed-1.8/blob/c5ead7f5f3/blog/views.py

Could you help me understand the expression **make_object_list = True**.
First of all, I tried to dig the inheritance chain of ArchiveIndexView. Secondly, I just commented it out and looked at the result. The result didn't change.

Well, I suppose, it is a mistake in the book. But maybe I'm wrong.

Could you help me understand for ArchiveIndexView in what base class or a mixin that make_object_list is defined?

Comment: `make_objects_list` is an attribute of [YearArchiveView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-date-based/#yeararchiveview) as far as I know. It could be a copy/paste left over.

Comment: I wrote that I suppose a mistake in the book. But as I'm a newbie, I decided to ask.